# Check if a class is a new instance or has at least once property populated before saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, nhibernate

I thought this would be an easy one but I can't think of a good way to do it.

User submits a webform. Based on submitted information I build three classes and assign their properties from received data:

```
UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
UserAddress userAddress = new UserAddress();
UserEmployer userEmployer = new UserEmployer();
```

Based on submitted information some classes end up being populated with properties and some do not.

What's the best way to check whether userInfo class, for example, ended up with properties assigned ? I don't want to save a particular object to the database if it doesn't have any real properties assigned and all of them are set to either null or "".

I only want to save the objects that ended up with at least one real property assigned.

ps. using NHibernate to save data to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection and loop through the properties, checking each one individually.

```
var type = userInfo.GetType();
var properties = type.GetProperties();
```

or if they're fields instead of properties

```
var fields = type.GetFields();
```

Then you could check each for null or some value.

Comment: Using reflection for 'normal' tasks is just too hacky, in my opinion.

Comment: Took this approach for a quick fix. Reflection + Linq : 

userInfo.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetValue(userInfo, null) != null &&
                    p.GetValue(userInfo, null).ToString()!=string.Empty);

I'm thinking about a Property driven method listed though.

Answer (score 3):

```
public interface IPersistable{
    bool ShouldPersist {get;}
}

public class MyPersistable:IPersistable
{
    private bool _persist;

    public MyPersistable(){}

    public string MyValue{
        get{
            return _myValue;
        }
        set{
            _persist = true;// or validate with !IsNullOrEmpty() first
            _myValue = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ShouldPersist{
        get{
            return _persist;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Only save if a property changes - don't just guess based on field values at the end. One further step may be necessary - there may need to be a method to reset the _persist field if the object is persisted, and/or if the object is being loaded from previously being persisted.

Comment: +1 
Nice approach, thank you. Unfortunately it won't work in my case as I"m working with entity classes here that I can't modify.
But maybe I'll create a View Model on top of it... let me think about it. THanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making an interface that all three classes implement, providing a function along the lines of `shouldSave()` or `hasSetProperties()`, which checks each data field and returns true if any of them are defined.

Maybe even a method to get all the data in a form you can easily pass into NHibernate.

Comment: And do a IsNullOrEmpty type of check on every single field ? 
There must be an easier way.. I hope.

Comment: @Shenaniganz: Well, every field that the object has that could be saved. If this is a problem, you may need to rethink the design of those classes

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an instance of that object, if you do not have any values that can be assigned to the properties of that object.

Next to that, 'UserAddress' should possibly not be an entity, but a value object.